# How to map an array key indexes into other key names from drop down list form controls?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I need to change the array key names into others specified by users, using drop down lists as reactive form controls.

Lets say I have the following array:

```
dataArray = [
    { id: 7854496, name: 'Peterson', gender: 'Male' },
    { id: 7054457, name: 'Peterson', gender: 'Female' },
    { id: 6954481, name: 'Peterson', gender: 'Female' },
];
```

The user will, will select the drop down list related to id, and change into another, lets say `index`, and so on for the others. Therefore, when the user click on the button with the `mapData()` method, the array should look like:

```
dataArray = [
    { index: 7854496, familyName: 'Peterson', sex: 'Male' },
    { index: 7054457, familyName: 'Peterson', sex: 'Female' },
    { index: 6954481, familyName: 'Peterson', sex: 'Female' },
];
```

Here is the `mapData()` method:

```
mapData() {
  this.odkDataIndexes.forEach((arrayIndexControl) => {
    let newIndex = this.indexesForm.get(arrayIndexControl).value;
    this.dataArray = this.dataArray.map((item) => {
      console.log(item);
      return {
        newIndex: item[arrayIndexControl]
      };
    });
  });
}
```

I am doing it this way, because, I am mapping some field to others, so I can do a migration from database into another, where the array should have a specific array key names.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdk8fe) having the full code.

Comment: Does it not work?

Comment: @NicholasK No. It is returning the same array, where each row have `newIndex: 58752`, and the other fields are dropped, and the number here is the value of each id.

Comment: First resolve the compilation errors along with the errors in the console.

Comment: @NicholasK done sir, the fiddle is working now https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdk8fe

Comment: As per your drop down, you are displaying all the options for each field. So for example, 1. can id be mapped to sex? 2. Can all options be mapped to the same field - what happens if I change all the fields to familyName? How would you differentiate in that case

Comment: @NicholasK it does not matter for now. Once the mapping is done, I will add restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
mapData() {    
    var newDataArray = [];
    this.dataArray.forEach(e=>{
      var newItem = {};
      this.odkDataIndexes.forEach((arrayIndexControl) =>{
        // console.log(e[arrayIndexControl]);
        newItem[this.indexesForm.get(arrayIndexControl).value] = e[arrayIndexControl];
      });
      newDataArray.push(newItem);
    });
    this.dataArray = newDataArray;
}
```

Comment: There is a bug withing the script. If I chose, 2 inputs from drop down list as the same, lets say, I want the `id` and `gender` to have the same new index, the script will drop one of them in the new array. (In my real life project, some field could take the same new field names)

Comment: You can't have two properties with the same name in a javascript object. If hypothetically it js has such a feature, then how will distinguish which property is mapped to which property.